# Express loading images relative to url

Tags: html, node.js, image, express, loading

I'm building a fairly basic webpage using express. However, I'm having some trouble with my image pathways.

This code works fine.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/app/public/")));
app.get("/overview", function(req, res) {    
    res.render('some-file');    
});
```

Inside of some-file.ejs I have...

```
<img src="assets/images/picture.jpg">
```

But what doesnt work is when I have a second url pathway.

```
app.get("/overview/specific", function(req, res) {    
    res.render('another-file');    
});

<img src="assets/images/picture.jpg">
```

In this example I'm trying to load the exact same image (in my case its a banner thats reused on every single page). This gives me an error that the image is not found. What I've noticed from the console errors is that the image is being loaded from localhost:3000/overview/assets/images/picture.jpg
I don't understand why express is trying to load the image from whatever the first pathway is (overview in this case). Overview shouldnt be in the pathway!
Can anyone help me out debugging this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your folder structure also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `/assets/images/picture.jpg`.

Add `/` before the path. Then it will take `/app/public/` as a root and be sure that the image will be at :

`/app/public/assets/images/picture.jpg`

Now wherever you want `picture.jpg` just pass this absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

We serve favicons dynamically using an ExpressJS redirect, it works very well.

First, we retrieve the site object from memory with a quick lookup based on req.hostname, then send this response:

```
res.redirect(site.favicon);
```

The favicon variable could be a static asset on our server, or an asset on another server too.  Our front-end code just calls /api/resources/favicon and it will receive the correct link in return.